# What's the difference between "method" and "process"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

I came across the following sentences in a political science book:

> "Political science—like other social sciences—seeks to study human
> behaviour through the use of a scientific method that, at times, can
> prompt objections and debate. This chapter points out that political
> science has changed over the centuries; the chapter further analyses
> relationships between political science and science, scientific
> processes, the use of scientific processes in analysing political
> data, and limitations of science."

How is "method" related to "process" and what makes it different from "process"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While they're very similar, I'd say that "method" might more often be used to refer to a general approach, whereas a "process" is typically a specific set of steps.

That said, the "scientific method" is a very specific term, and it's possible that they're referring there to the scientific method as a single thing, and later the processes they refer to are individual procedures.